# SQL - simple 'OR' not working!

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL - Stumped on a SELECT - please help!!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4552135/sql-stumped-on-a-select-please-help)

Hello! I've got 2 tables:
**myTable1** - stores usernames & user_ids
**myTable2** - stores emails & user_ids

What I'm trying to do is return a row(s) of a username, email, both or none depending on which (or both) is taken. I'm using the following code but getting strange results!

```
SELECT usr.username, pro.email 
FROM myTable1 AS usr, myTable2 AS pro
WHERE usr.username = 'wookie' OR pro.email = 'wookie@woo.com'
```

I'm expecting to receive two columns of 1 row. 
**Column:** username , **row:** 'wookie' and
 **Column:** email, **row:** 'wookie@woo.com'

However I'm getting 'wookie' repeating countlessly in the username column, and the email column has just output rows of all the users' emails  (not the one I specified in the statement).

Am I doing something wrong??

Comment: this looks exactly like the question you asked an hour ago....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4552135/sql-stumped-on-a-select-please-help

Comment: There is no reason to tag both mysql and sql-server ...

Answer (score 2):

```
select 
  usr.username, pro.email 
from 
  myTable1 as usr
inner join 
  myTable2 as pro
on usr.user_ids=pro.user_ids
WHERE 
(usr.username='wookie' OR pro.email='wookie@woo.com');
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for a join or something like that.

```
SELECT 
  usr.username, 
  pro.email 
FROM 
  myTable1 AS usr 
  join myTable2 AS pro ON usr.user_ids = pro.user_ids
WHERE 
  usr.username = 'wookie' OR pro.email = 'wookie@woo.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a join command i think:

```
    Select
    usr.username,
    pro.email

    from mytable1 usr

    inner join mytable2 pro
    on usr.user_id = pro.user_id

    Where Statement
```